# Action Mailer is not run properly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying implementing send mail through action mailer in rails
related code are..

**initializer\setup_mail.rb**

```
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address     =>"smtp.gmail.com",
    :domain      =>"gmail.com",
    :port        => 587,
    :user_name   =>"Debasis",
    :password    =>"************",
    :authentication =>"plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto =>true
  }
```

**my mailers/user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "bkdebasish90@gamil.com"
  def registration_confirmation(user)
    mail(:to=>user.email, :subject =>"Registered")
  end
end
```

**and users.controller is**

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  respond_to do |format| 
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

my devlopment log is --

```
    UserMailer#registration_confirmation: processed outbound mail in 306.0ms

     Sent mail to debasish.svin@gmail.com (2924.2ms)
     Date: Wed, 13 Jul 2016 19:02:43 +0530
      From: bkdebasish90@gamil.com
       To: debasish.svin@gmail.com
      Message-ID: <578642fb9cf1a_1b085217834727ad@debashis-PC.mail>
      Subject: Registered
     Mime-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=UTF-8
      Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

       Hi sir you signed in ....completed
     Redirected to http://localhost:9292/users/18
      Completed 302 Found in 3356ms (ActiveRecord: 86.0ms)
```

and i see all are work fine.. but email is not come

Comment: What do you have in `config/environments/development.rb` ?  I would've expected to see there...   `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp; 
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   (settings go here)
  }`

Comment: You dont need to create new file in initializers just add the config details in development.rb

Comment: I have tried above answer.......but still now i am facing same issue

Comment: Please do post something meaningful for the next time. You have just posted your file name and some of the code snippets. Ok,,thats enough?? see, you understand your problem well, not us. So when you are trying to post something,then please do it in a brief manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add above settings in development.rb as following:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address     =>"smtp.gmail.com",
 :domain      =>"gmail.com",
 :port        => 587,
 :user_name   =>"Debasis",
 :password    =>"************",
 :authentication =>"plain",
 :enable_starttls_auto =>true
}
```

Comment: I have tried above answer.......but still now i am facing same issue ...i am using the port 9292..

Answer (score 1):

Here, Your **initializer\setup_mail.rb** setting will go to the **development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address     =>"smtp.gmail.com",
 :domain      =>"gmail.com",
 :port        => 587,
 :user_name   =>"Debasis",
 :password    =>"************",
 :authentication =>"plain",
 :enable_starttls_auto =>true
}
```

and I think you need to use `deliver_now` instead of `deliver` in your **users.controller** 
Try to replace this line

```
UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
```

with

```
UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver_now
```

Hope this will work for you. Thanks!